# Tikz primitive with scale factor of zero does not vanish

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm inputting some `.tikz` files generated by a program which I can not modify. These files contain many occurances of a basic `tikz` primitive with its scale key-value set to zero. All primitives with a scale of zero should be ignored. However, tikz does not ignore them. Take this MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [anchor= east] (1.9,2.53686) node[scale=1.28308, rotate=0]{-3000};
    \draw [anchor= east] (1.9,2.53686) node[scale=0, rotate=0]{-3000};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd expect that there is just one label `-3000`, however, after compiling (pdflatex) there are two with different sizes [Note: I've tested this with acroread, evince and okular. acroread prints an error and shows two labels, evince just prints the two labels and okular prints just one but is not able to print the document].

Is there some way to tell tikz to ignore all primitives with a scale of zero? My current workaround is a tiny script which puts a comment sign before any line containing the string `scale=0,`, however, this is not really a robust fix.

Comment: I see only -3000 with SumatraPDF and AcroRead,  but why would you want this ? Just don't put that node there no? And can you include what you mean by a *primitive*?

Comment: @percusse by primitive I mean something like `\draw`, i.e. a command which creates a graphical primitive (essentially a dot/line). The problem is that the code is autogenerated and I can't influence that these nodes are inserted into the file. The generator _hides_ them by setting `scale=0`, however this does not work as expected (at least for my combination of texlive/evince).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally had no trouble displaying the document as it was intended (i.e. the second node does not appear in either Okular or Acrobat Reader), but anyway: you can use the `.prefix code` handler to add some code that will make the element invisible. I think this should work:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
 scale/.prefix code={\pgfmathnot{#1}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/opacity=0}\fi}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [anchor= east] (1.9,2.53686) node[scale=1.28308, rotate=0]{-3000};
    \draw [anchor= east] (1.9,2.53686) node[scale=0, rotate=0]{-3000};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you have a better way of making something invisible than setting its opacity to zero, use that. (As far as I know there's no style for "don't render this at all".)

Comment: What about `\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/font=\nullfont}` ?

Comment: That would work for a text node, I suppose, but not for a drawn or filled path.